# What is the difference between locals and globals when using Python's eval()?

Tags: python, eval

Why does it make a difference if variables are passed as globals or as locals to Python's function [eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)?

As also [described in the documenation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval), Python will copy `__builtins__` to globals, if not given explicitly. But there must be also some other difference which I cannot see.

Consider the following example function. It takes a string `code` and returns a function object. Builtins are not allowed (e.g. `abs()`), but all functions from the `math` package.

```
def make_fn(code):
    import math
    ALLOWED_LOCALS = {v:getattr(math, v)
        for v in filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), dir(math))
    }
    return eval('lambda x: %s' % code, {'__builtins__': None}, ALLOWED_LOCALS)
```

It works as expected not using any local or global objects:

```
   fn = make_fn('x + 3')
   fn(5) # outputs 8
```

But it does not work using the `math` functions:

```
   fn = make_fn('cos(x)')
   fn(5)
```

This outputs the following exception:

```
   <string> in <lambda>(x)
   NameError: global name 'cos' is not defined
```

But when passing the same mapping as globals it works:

```
def make_fn(code):
   import math
   ALLOWED = {v:getattr(math, v)
      for v in filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), dir(math))
   }
   ALLOWED['__builtins__'] = None
   return eval('lambda x: %s' % code, ALLOWED, {})
```

Same example as above:

```
   fn = make_fn('cos(x)')
   fn(5) # outputs 0.28366218546322625
```

What happens here in detail?

Comment: In the documentation it is said "globals dictionary is present and lacks ‘__builtins__’". I guess that's mean that the key ‘__builtins__’ is not present, but in your example, you set it to None. I suggest you should change ALLOWED[‘__builtins__’] = None by del ALLOWED[‘__builtins__’] and try it again.

Comment: @jorispilot My issue is not connected to __builtins__. I just mentioned it, because there is this special casing of the globals by eval. The way I set __builtins__ to None is correct, if you want to forbid builtin functions such as `abs`. `cos` is not a built function, it is part of the `math` module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python looks up names as globals by default; only names assigned to in *functions* are looked up as locals (so any name that is a parameter to the function or was assigned to in the function).

You can see this when you use the `dis.dis()` function to decompile code objects or functions:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def func(x):
...     return cos(x)
... 
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (cos)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

`LOAD_GLOBAL` loads `cos` as a global name, only looking in the globals namespace. The `LOAD_FAST` opcode uses the current namespace (function locals) to look up names by index (function local namespaces are highly optimized and stored as a C array).

There are three more opcodes to look up names; `LOAD_CONST` (reserved for true constants, such as `None` and literal definitions for immutable values), `LOAD_DEREF` (to reference a closure) and `LOAD_NAME`. The latter does look at both locals and globals and is only used when a function code object could not be optimized, as `LOAD_NAME` is a lot slower.

If you *really* wanted `cos` to be looked up in `locals`, you'd have to force the code to be unoptimised; this *only* works in Python 2, by adding a `exec()` call (or `exec` statement):

```
>>> def unoptimized(x):
...     exec('pass')
...     return cos(x)
... 
>>> dis.dis(unoptimized)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('pass')
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 EXEC_STMT           

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (cos)
             11 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

Now `LOAD_NAME` is used for `cos` because for all Python knows, the `exec()` call added that name as a local.

Even in this case, the locals `LOAD_NAME` looks into, will be the locals of the function itself, and not the locals passed to `eval`, which are for only for the parent scope.

Comment: I did not really understand your answer. Consider the function: `def fn():
    a = 1;
    print 'a in locals?', 'a' in locals();
    print 'a in globals?', 'a' in globals();
    return (lambda: a)()` - why does this work, but not `eval('lambda: a', {}, {'a': 1})()`?

Comment: Because each scope has its *own* locals. `eval` is the parent scope, the `lambda` gets its own scope, its own `locals()`.

Comment: Same situation as in the first function, isn't it? `a` is in the locals of `fn` and then used in the lambda function. In the second example, `a` is in the locals of `eval` and then used in the lambda function.

Comment: No, it isn't. Sorry, should have looked a little deeper. The compiler marks `a` in the `fn` a *closure*, which the nested lambda then references (`LOAD_DEREF`). You cannot build a closure with `eval()` and a locals dictionary; there the unbound `a` is marked a global instead, there is no parent function scope with `a` as a local. The dictionary passed into `eval` is not consulted at compile time.