# eval globals and locals argument do not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.5

The statement eval'd does not seem to actually be executed in an environment with the corresponding globals and locals objects.

```
def f(x):
    return g(x)*3
def g(x):
    return x**2
funcs = {"f":f,"g":g}
del globals()['g'] # to keep them out of the global environment
del globals()['f']
eval("f(2)",globals(),funcs)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

**Update:**

More illustration:

```
>>> exec("print(globals()['g'])",{**globals(),**funcs})
<function g at 0x7feb627aaf28>
>>> eval("f(2)",{**globals(),**funcs})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488078/what-is-the-difference-between-locals-and-globals-when-using-pythons-eval).  The function g fails to look up even when passed as a global.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, as the NameError occurs in globals as well.  It's not a globals vs locals problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you defined `f`, it decided that the reference to `g` was a global name lookup.  Furthermore, it retained a reference to the global environment in effect at the point of definition (that's what lets you call functions in other modules without depriving them of their original globals).

When you then deleted `g`, you fundamentally broke `f` - this global lookup of `g` will now fail.

The global/local environment parameters to your `exec` call do not have ANY effect whatsoever on the already-compiled function `f`.  They only affect the actual text that you exec'ed: `"f(2)"`.  In other words, the only name lookup that actually uses the environment you provided is that of `f` itself.

Comment: Is there some way to eval(f) in an environment that I provide?

Comment: Well, you could `exec` the body of the function (instead of a call to the function), or use the `types` module to construct a new function object with a different `func_globals` than the original.  Or you could avoid this convoluted mess completely: if a function's operation needs to be customized, then *pass those details in as parameters*.

Comment: Well, to put this in context, I'm putting together a distributed computing system that allows remote execution of f.  viz.  I create a bunch of code on a jupyter notebook, discover that f takes weeks, ship f and all of it's requirements to the big mean server, the big mean server crunches it and hands back the results.  My thought was that I could just ship everything in globals() along and it would just execute.  This was apparently incorrect.  =c)

Comment: `types.FunctionType(f.__code__, funcs, f.__name__, f.__defaults__, f.__closure__)` did it.  We are charged to open source this whole mess.  I'll post a link to it on this thread somehow when we do.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is can be seen by looking at the bytecode compiled from the
 definition of function `f()` using `dis.dis(f)`:

```
  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (g)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              8 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the first instruction tries to load a **global** named `g`.

One way to make it work would be to make `g()` a local function:

```
def f(x):
    def g(x):
        return x**2

    return g(x)*3

funcs = {"f": f}
del globals()['f'] # to keep it  out of the global environment
print(eval("f(2)", globals(), funcs))  # -> 12
```

Here's the bytecode from the revised `f()` for comparison:

```
  8           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object g at 0x00546288, file "test.py">)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.g')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (g)

 11           8 LOAD_FAST                1 (g)
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             16 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: >>> exec("print(globals()['g'])",{**globals(),**funcs})
<function g at 0x7feb627aaf28>  Seems to suggest that there is, in fact, a global named 'g' that the environment should have access to?  What is the point of being able to pass in a globals object if the eval/exec functions does not use it for looking up objects?  Indeed, where IS it looking for g, if not in globals()?

Comment: @Scott: When `eval("f(2)", globals(), funcs)` executes there is a `g()` function, but it's in the dictionary being passed as the _`locals`_ argument to `eval()`, so the `LOAD_GLOBAL` at the beginning of its bytecode fails.

Comment: How about >>> eval("f(2)",{**globals(),**funcs})?  That can't find g either.

Comment: @Scott: OK, i see what you  mean—and agree _that_ doesn't make sense (nor agree with the documentation). Perhaps it should be reported as a bug.